# Getting Member String from Class C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a class that contain some game level settings.

```
class Stage {
private: 
    int level;
    int stars;
    std::string imgName;

public:
    int getLevel(){ return level; };
    void setLevel(int n){ level = n; };

    int getStars(){ return stars; };
    void setStars(int n){ stars = n; };

    std::string getImgName(){ return imgName; };
    void setImgName(std::string name){ imgName = name; };
};
```

Then in my program I set the info.

```
Stage* stagesArr = new Stage[3];

stagesArr[0].setLevel(0);
stagesArr[0].setStars(1200);
stagesArr[0].setImgName("stage0.png");
```

Then if I want to get this info the string is giving me an odd output.

```
CCLOG("Level: %i", stagesArr[0].getLevel()); 
CCLOG("Required stars: %i", stagesArr[0].getStars());
CCLOG("Image Name: %s", stagesArr[0].getImgName());

//Level:0
//Required stars: 1200
//Image Name: T%s //Or just random stuff.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try `CCLOG("Image Name: %s", stagesArr[0].getImgName().c_str());`?

Comment: What exactly does `CCLOG()` do?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your time. CCLOG does nothing but showing me whats happening. If I try to use the method c_str() there is an error: 

    Stage* stagesArr Error: expression must have class type

The type is an array, but I don't know what to do with this error. Greetings

Comment: You did `#include <string>`, didn't you? Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please. Where does `CCLOG()` come from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ <string> is included, but the error is there. I'm working with Cocos2d-x so CCLOG is what they call a Macro from Cocos that log in the console the required info, Integers in the first two cases, and a String in the last one.

Comment: _@Diego_ Sorry for the confusion, I fixed my answer with the correct code.

Comment: Flawless explanation and coding guidelines. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suspected that `CCLOG()` uses the same formatting rules like the [**`<x>printf()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function family does, you need to pass a `const char*` with the format specifier `%s`.

Your `getImgName()` returns a `std::string` value though, which isn't directly compatible with a `const char*`.

To achieve the latter, you should call the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function:

```
 CCLOG("Image Name: %s", stagesArr[0].getImgName().c_str());
```

---

Also you can improve your getter/setter functions specifying `const`ness applicability more clear:

```
   int getLevel() const { return level; }
               // ^^^^^^ 
   int getStars() const { return stars; }
               // ^^^^^^ 
   const std::string& getImgName() const { return imgName; }
// ^^^^^                       // ^^^^^^ 
void setImgName(const std::string& name) { imgName = name; }
             // ^^^^^
```

---

**Note:**
As a matter of style you can omit the `get` / `set` prefixes for getter/setter functions in c++, as the signatures are disambiguate enough:

```
int Level() const { return level; }
void Level(int n){ level = n; }

int Stars() const { return stars; }
void Stars(int n){ stars = n; }

const std::string& ImgName() const { return imgName; }
void ImgName(const std::string& name){ imgName = name; }
```

My personally preferred style is to use lower caps and disambiguate class member variables with a `_` postfix:

```
class Stage {
private: 
    int level_;
    int stars_;
    std::string img_name_;

public:
    int level() const { return level_; }
    void level(int n) { level_ = n; }

    int stars() const { return stars_; }
    void stars(int n){ stars_ = n; }

    const std::string& img_name() const { return img_name_; }
    void img_name(const std::string& name) { img_name_ = name; };
};
```